# LaravelExcel está convertendo os valores do cabeçalho de uma planilha excel. Como desabilitar isso?

Tags: laravel, microsoft-excel, laravel-5, phpexcel

Estou usando a biblioteca LaravelExcel para importar os dados de um excel para um banco de dados.

Para pegar os dados do cabeçalho da minha planilha, faço o seguinte:

```
Excel::load('file.xls', function($reader) {

     $nomeDasColunas = $reader->get()->first()->keys();

});
```

Porém estou com o seguinte problema: Quando o meu cabeçalho vem com nomes com acentuação, hifens e outros caracteres, estão sendo convertidos.

Por exemplo. Os valores:

```
Nome | E-mail | Número do Cartão
```

Está sendo convertido para

```
 nome | email | numero_do_cartao
```

O problema é que eu preciso dos nomes originais. Não quero criar uma função para "reconverter" os valores para os nomes originais, pois isso seria um tiro no pé.

Procurei essa solução em tudo quanto é lugar e não achei. Olhei até mesmo no código-fonte da própria biblioteca, mas não encontrei nenhum método que eu possa definir a forma com que os cabeçalhos são lidos.

Existe alguma configuração dessa biblioteca onde eu possa mudar essa conversão de nomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo. Não existe realmente nenhum método na classe `Excel` que faça a operação de desativar a conversão automática dos nomes das colunas, mas é possível configurar a biblioteca.

Existem duas formas de fazer isso.

A primeira é quando se trata de um caso específico. Não quero desativar a conversão automática para importação de todos os excels, mas apenas para uma  operação específica. Podemos usar a função `config` e definir um valor para `excel.import.heading`.

assim:

```
config(['excel.import.heading' => 'original']);
```

Usei a opção `original` para manter os cabeçalhos originais de acordo com o excel enviado.

A segunda foram seria alterando o arquivo de configuração do LaravelExcel, para obter essas configurações de importação globalmente.

Para fazer isso, basta rodar o comando `php artisan vendor:publish` e, depois de o arquivo `config/excel.php` ser criado, editar o valor do `array` contendo o índice `heading` (que está dentro de `import`).
As opções disponíveis são:

`true|false|slugged|slugged_with_count|ascii|numeric|hashed|trans|original`